# Turn off ValidationSummary client side in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

My form is a wizard like form which does client side validation for each step, clicking next, and then the server side validation is done when the use clicks "Submit" at the end of the wizard.

I am using

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

in my page, and it seems like this causes the validation summary to show each time a user clicks next and the `$("form").validate(); is triggered.

I want this validation summary only to be visible after the server side validation is done and failed, since my inline validations messages may be not be visible depending on which step the validation failed on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need to disable validation summary via javascript.  Try this on your next button on a javascript function

```
function foo()
{
    var myvalidator= document.getElementById('validatorControlId');  
        ValidatorEnable(myvalidator, false);   
        ValidationSummaryOnSubmit();
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for a different answer on this one, but it seems that this could be a way to go. Thank you.